# How do I post form data from a static website to a mysql database without using router and ejs modules

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, forms, action

I am new to backend dev and having been battling with this problem for about two weeks now despite having gone through copious video tutorials and books which have not addressed the nature of my problem.I would be very grateful if anyone could come to my aid. Below are some relevant details
The HTML Form

```
<div class="wrap">
       <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                        <form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" required placeholder="First Name">
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" required placeholder="Last Name">
                            <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="E-mail">
                            <input type="password" name="password" required placeholder="Password">
                            <input type="password" name="password" required placeholder="Password">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

The server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const mysql = require("mysql");


let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'couriersystem'
});


var port = 3000;


app.post('/', function (request, response) {
    let sql = `INSERT INTO clients(firstname, lastname, email, password)
           VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`;

    // execute the insert statment
    connection.query(sql);

    connection.end();
});
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Server listening on port" + port);
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index.html")
});
```

Comment: What is the `INSERT` query suppose to insert? You didn't define the variables.

Answer (score 0):

- The`action` argument of your `<form>` tag should point to the full HTTP(S) address of your endpoint published with express.
- Your SQL statement should get, FILTER and inject the form data received in the [`request.query`](https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#req) object.

Comment: Please what exactly is this full HTTP(S) address of my endpoint published with express, is it in my server file?

Comment: @Nsoha — That suggests you've missed something fundamental. How are you executing `server.js` in the first place? (e.g. with pm2, running node.js directly from the comment line, something else?)

Comment: @Nsoha Your `server.js` is a node file and must be executed in order to listen to incoming requests. You most probably should read the Express Quick Start Guide.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate

Comment: In this case, please confirm the anwser so others who would experience the same issue could access this page and easily identify the most relevant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this suggestion:

```
app.post('/', function (request, response) {
    /*get value and set as variables from the html form*/
    let fname = request.body.firstname;
    let lname = request.body.lastname;
    let email = request.body.email;
    let pwd = request.body.password;

    let sql = `INSERT INTO clients(firstname, lastname, email, password)
           VALUES('${fname}','${lname}','${email}','${pwd}')`;

    // execute the insert statment
    connection.query(sql, function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {
            return response.status(500).send(err); /*return error message if insert unsuccessful*/
            }
        else {
            connection.end();
            response.redirect('/'); /*redirecting the page after successful insert*/
   }
  })
});
```

Also edit your html form to add `"/"` in action, hence:

```
 <form action="/" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
```